# OpenGL es 2.0 glDrawElements Implementation

Tags: opengl-es

OpenGLes 2.0 does not have support for special built-in fragment shader variable called **gl_PrimitiveID**. I tried to simulate this variable by associating a unique attribute with each of the vertices forming a triangle. But this causes problem when there is sharing of vertices between two or more triangles. It would effectively require duplication of shared vertices for this technique to work increasing memory usage for complex scenes.

I am thinking to make changes in the openGLes library itself so as to be able to maintain **gl_PrimitiveID** variable internally. I am using mesa 3d library for editing the source code of openGLes 2.0. But I am not able to locate the implementation of **glDrawElements** to serve my purpose. This function has **GL_APIENTRY** flag associated with its declaration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If a single vertex is indeed part of two faces, while the vertex shader is being run for it, what face/primitive index would you expect to associate with it? What is the logic you employ to choose which of the two primitives it is part of?

Comment: OpenGL or OpenGL-ES are not libraries. They're system level APIs, which implementation is buried deep within the GPU's driver. You can't make changes to them, without messing around in a GPU driver.

Comment: @balajeerc: He want's to get the primitive ID, i.e. the internal number assigned to each individual primitive in turn. See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_PrimitiveID.xml a feature of OpenGL >= 3 but not found in OpenGL-ES.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL or OpenGL-ES are not libraries. They're system level APIs, which implementation is buried deep within the GPU's driver. You can't make changes to them, without messing around in a GPU driver's code. And then everybody who used your program had to use that driver. Which in the case of OpenGL-ES will be impossible to carry out, because most OpenGL-ES implementations live in devices that build walled gardens around applications. Also the driver's source codes are usually kept a secret.

Comment: Mesa is OpenSourced, he's right in that regard. That of course doesn't matter, because all other points are valid here, and this whole question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think what he is trying to do is this: for any given vertex, he wants to know the index of the primitive it is part of, inside the vertex shader.

Comment: @balajeerc: Yes, that much I did understand as well.

Comment: Is there any way I can keep track of the gl_PrimitiveID in openGLes ?

Comment: @AnkitVijay: Apart from splitting up primitives, unsharing vertices and provide a kind-of primitive ID as a supplemental vertex attribute: No. However the biggest problem with that is not increased memory footprint, but more vertex cache misses, because there are no more shared vertices.